# Triangulo en java

Tags: java, netbeans

Soy nueva en este tema de java,y quiero realizar la siguiente figura. Debería salir así:

```
***  
**  
*
```

He utilizado el siguiente código:

```
public class MATRIZ {  
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++) {  
      for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {  
        System.out.print( "*" );  
      }  
      System.out.println();  
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El primer for tiene que iniciar en orden inverso de mayor a menor y en el segundo for cambiar el limite de la variable i por la variable j

```
public class MATRIZ {  
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    for(int j=3; j>0; j--) {  
      for(int i=0; i<j; i++) {  
        System.out.print( "*" );  
      }  
      System.out.println();  
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

te dejo debajo una clase con un metodo en donde puedes hacer lo que necesitas, los valores se lo puedes pasar por teclado.

public class escaleraAsteriscoV2 {

```
static Scanner escaner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Digite cantidasd de peldanos ");
    int entrdadasteriscos = escaner.nextInt();
    llenarEscaleraInversa(entrdadasteriscos);
}
```

static void llenarEscaleraInversa(int asteriscos){
       for (int i =asteriscos ;i>0;i--){

```
       for (int j=i;j>0;j--){
           System.out.print("*");

       }
       System.out.println("");
   }
```

}

}